# Android Checkbox White Border

Tags: java, android, xml, checkbox

How do I change the checkbox to have a white border? I added the checkbox to a dark colored background and as you can see, it's barely visible.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create a 2 different drawable for checked state & non checked state. example-

### checkbox_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/white_color_box_with_tick" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/white_color_box_without_tick" />
</selector>
```

And set this drawable in the following way-

```
<CheckBox
    android:text="Custom CheckBox"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_selector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: are these drawable checkboxes images?

Comment: yes, they are full checkbox images

Comment: What is **white_color_box_without_tick**?  What do they resemble?

Comment: image drawable. imagine a white box without the check/tick icon